# glDiscardFrameBufferEXT undefined in Android, is there an equivalent?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am currently in the process of converting a framework (OpenGL ES 1.1, with extensions) to Android. Trouble is, the framework uses frame buffers, yet glDiscardFramebufferEXT returns an error that it is undefined.

My Android.mk uses -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES to get the GL extensions (anything with OES tag).

Is there a workaround for this? Or do I have to make Android specific changes here? (Or maybe I'm just missing something.)

(This framework is compatible with IOS, so I figured the GL code would be similar, if not the exact same.)

Thanks.

Comment: Is the "GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer" extension available?

Comment: Seems to not be, IOS supports it but Android does not, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DiscardFramebuffer is a performance hint to the OpenGL driver: it can always be trivially removed or ignored without visible impact.

If the extension isn't available, then you can just remove the calls.

Comment: Thanks, guess my problem is somewhere else.